# Porque razão consigo restaurar antigo valor de ESP

Tags: c, assembly, x86

Boas tenho aqui uma questão que envolve assembly e C.

A variável `format` tem mais que 4 bytes, mesmo assim consigo fazer `push`dela sem usar cast e retormar o antigo valor de ESP depois de fazer push. Como é que é possivel?

ASM

```
segment .data
 format db "oleeee %d",10,0;tem muito mais que 4 bytes

segment .text
    global  _my_func
    extern _printf
    extern _soma


 _my_func:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp ;inicio 

    push dword [numero]
    push dword format
    call _printf
    add esp, 8 ;remover

    push dword 5
    push dword 200
    call _soma
    add esp,8 ;remover

    push eax
    push dword format
    call _printf


    mov esp,ebp
    pop ebp ;fim
    ret
```

C

```
int soma(int a, int b){

return a+b;
 }

 int main()
 {
   int ret_status;
   ret_status = my_func();
   return ret_status;
 }
```

Comment: Quando você da o push em `format` vc da o push no endereço de memória dela não no valor, e `ESP` está salvo em `EBP`, uma coisa que está faltando no seu código, é o retorno de `my_func()`, no caso ela está retornado quanquer lixo, para retornar um valor, vc tem q usar o `EAX`.

Comment: Ah, que mal ;p Eu sei que tenho de dar valor a EAX, neste caso não foi necessário porque não faço nada com o seu retorno.